# Присвоение значения переменной

Tags: c#

Почему не присваивается значение в зависимости от условий ?

```
private void kotorijChas()
{
    string localDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    string[] t1 = localDate.Split(' ');
    string t2 = t1[1];
    string[] t3 = t2.Split(':');
    int t4 = int.Parse(t3[0]);

    string vremySutok;

        if (t4 > 04 && t4 <= 10)
        {
            vremySutok = "доброе утро";
        }

        else if (t4 > 10 && t4 <= 17)
        {
            vremySutok = "добрый день";
        }

        else if (t4 > 17 && t4 <= 23)
        {
            vremySutok = "добрый вечер";
        }

        else if (t4 >= 00 && t4 <= 04)
        {
            vremySutok = "доброй ночи";
        }

    textBox1.AppendText(vremySutok);


}// Определяем Утро|День|Вечер|Ночь
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто на будущее. Чтоб вот такое не писать: `string[] t3 = t2.Split(':');
    int t4 = int.Parse(t3[0]);` у `DateTime` есть много полезных свойств: `string hours = localDate.Hour.ToString();`, `string minuties = localDate.Minute.ToString();` и далее в том же духе.

Comment: @Bulson Спасибо xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`string` - ссылочный тип, поэтому если вы в него явно ничего не записали там будет `null`

Ну и у вас в последнем if отсутствует else, поэтому компилятор не может быть уверен, что переменная точно будет проинициализирована

Вам следует либо инициализировать переменную при ее объявлении:

```
string vremySutok = "";
```

либо в последнем условии добавить else:

```
else vremySutok = "";
```

если же значение `null` также допустимо, то вы должны указать его явно:

```
string vremySutok = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

`string` - это ссылочный тип

Компилятор не может быть уверен, что сработает хотя бы один `if`

Comment: `Числовые литералы, начинающиеся с нуля - это восьмеричная система счисления` - разве это к шарпу относится?

Comment: @Андрей, да, точно, там этого вроде бы нет) Спасибо. Хотя, все равно такой код бы читающего смутил.